# ionic tab menu hide a item for after logging

Tags: php, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I make to ionicframework hidden a item.

For example home, log-in, sign-in (tab menu items)

user after logging(tab menu items); home, profile, message etc.

how can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

use any flag for this .
Like before login use any variable `var login="false"` and after login `login="true"` then in menu.html use **`ng-if`** .
I am not sharing full code use 
like

```
<div ng-if="login">home ,profile,message </div>
<div ng-if="login='false'">login,sign up </div>
```

Comment: You can explain, because I didn't this :/

Comment: make a global variable var In CONTROLLER.JS  isLoggedIn=false; then in login success function use **isLoggedIn=true;** and in login fail function use **isLoggedIn=false;** then in MENU.HTML use                                    <ion-list ng-hide="isLoggedIn"> 
         <ion-item  href="#/app/login">Login</ion-item>
        <ion-item  href="#/app/regist">Register</ion-item>
 </ion-list>                                                                                                            <ion-list ng-show="isLoggedIn" ><ion-item href="#/app/home">Dashboard</ion-item> </ion-list>

Comment: Did you get it now?